# Short story about alien invaders encountering prairie dogs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This was a one-page ultra short story, maybe three paragraphs. I read it no later than mid-80s in a random story collection and it was probably a lot older than that.

There isn’t much to it:

An alien spaceship lands on some empty place and an alien being emerges. Some curious prairie dogs pop up to see what’s going on, and the alien(s) immediately kill them for sport.

Then,

> Suddenly a hidden turret comes up from underground and destroys alien and ship in one blast with a futuristic weapon. One of the prairie dogs operating the turret quips to its companion: “funny, I always thought the humans would be the first ones to try.”

I can’t remember the book, story title or author. Weirdly, I came up empty when searching on the internet. You would think this would be easy to locate.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is *[The Thing from Outer Space and the Prairie Dogs](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?81842)* (1964) by Gahan Wilson.

Printed in its complete form below:

> A rocket ship landed on the Texas panhandle one
> bright, sunny day, in the middle of a prairie dog
> colony. The top of the rocket unscrewed, with
> a harsh, grating noise, and out crawled a Thing
> from outer space. The Thing carried a death
> ray, a mind twister, a pain amplifier, and many
> other ingenious instruments of war, torture, and
> destruction. It drooled green drool and looked
> about for something to kill.
>
> When a prairie dog peeped out from its burrow, the Thing spun on its
> tentacles, and shot out a blinding beam of fire from one of its weapons that reduced the prairie dog to a cloud of idly drifting ash. The Thing burbled for joy and started hunting eagerly for more of the tiny creatures.
> At this point, two cleverly concealed trap doors opened in the ground,
> and from each of them rose a glittering, electronic cannon manned by a
> crew of uniformed prairie dogs. The cannons fired simultaneously on the
> Thing and destroyed it.
>
> “It’s a good thing we were prepared,” said the captain of the prairie dogs, **“But I could have sworn the humans would have launched the first attack.”**

Comment: For the record, I searched Google Books for [the exact phrases ("The humans would" and "Prairie dogs")](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the+humans+would%22+%22prairie%22&sca_esv=585695356&tbm=bks&sxsrf=AM9HkKnuV8MSOc16InjhLkL0yFcpP_k9yg%3A1701114391817&ei=F_JkZaTFMZWDhbIP2eacqAw&ved=0ahUKEwjkrK_4-OSCAxWVQUEAHVkzB8UQ4dUDCAk&uact=5&oq=%22the+humans+would%22+%22prairie%22&gs_lp=Eg1nd3Mtd2l6LWJvb2tzIhwidGhlIGh1bWFucyB3b3VsZCIgInByYWlyaWUiSMMZUPMDWNIYcAF4AJABAJgBc6ABmAuqAQQxNy4xuAEDyAEA-AEBiAYB&sclient=gws-wiz-books)

Comment: Nice! That was really quick. I’ll accept I when the system lets me.

Comment: @EuroMicelli - [Always a pleasure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)

Comment: I'm curious about the legality of copying an entire 3 paragraph story like this to a publicly accessible domain. It feels like this violates copyright.

Comment: @Nzall - Given the extremely short length of the story, reporroducing it completely is probably acceptable. Ultimately the author is dead, so he's unlikely to complain.

Comment: @Valorum The author might be dead, but it's unlikely he's dead for more than 95 years, so the story isn't in public domain yet. Story length has nothing to do with it. Copyright is automatically granted.

Comment: @Nzall - True, but it also needs to be exercised. Someone (typically the author or the publisher) needs to *care* about the alleged misuse before they issue the customer legal letters and takedown requests.

Comment: Using the question as a prompt chat-gpt wrote a story https://pastebin.com/2TeJs4RY that I think you'd have trouble differentiating from the original if you'd heard them both a while back. So it's not exactly a complex/imaginative story, but I don't know if that has any bearing on copyright or anything.

Comment: @Nzall: In the US, copyrights granted before 1978 had to be renewed at the appropriate time, or else they automatically expired. US copyright law is really complicated, and it is entirely possible that this short story is in the public domain in the US. Many older pulp works from the 50s and 60s were seen as low-value and their copyrights were never renewed.

Comment: @SamDean Considering that ChatGPT was trained, not only with this kind of entry, but very likely *this very entry,* it's no wonder at all that ChatGPT burped up something nearly identical. "AI" is neither magical nor intelligent.

Comment: +1 just for the phrase, "Printed in its complete form below," which I may never read on another post on this or any other Stack.